# Angular 6 structural directive

Tags: angular, angular-directive

I have tried about as simple a structural directive with Angular 6 as you can. I created a project and then generated a new directive. The directive was added to the declations section of the @NgModule. Added the directive to the  of the app.component.html but I keep getting

> Can't bind to 'appHasPermission' since it isn't a known property of 'div'. ("> > ]*appHasPermission="good">

app.component.html

```html
<div *appHasPermission="good">
  <h1>Hello</h1>
</div>
```

directive

```js
import {Directive, Input, TemplateRef, ViewContainerRef} from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[appHasPermission]'
})
export class HasPermissionDirective {

  @Input() set permissionName(name: any) {
    this.viewContainerRef.createEmbeddedView(this.templateRef);
  }

  constructor(private templateRef: TemplateRef<any>, private viewContainerRef: ViewContainerRef) { }

}
```

and the module

```js
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HasPermissionDirective } from './has-permission.directive';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    HasPermissionDirective
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

I have looked at tutorials and video and they so exactly what I have done. It has to be something obvious.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of ways you can leverage to fix your issue:

1) Change `@Input` name:

```
@Input() set appHasPermission(name: any) {
  ...
}
```

2) Define `@Input` alias:

```
@Input('appHasPermission') set permissionName(name: any) {
  ...
}
```